# Variadic templated delegate in C++CX for use in non managed variadic template class

Tags: templates, delegates, interop, uwp, c++-cx

You can apply templates to ref classes in C++CX, you can apply them to normal classes.  You can't, apparently, apply a template to a delegate and reference it such that the compiler will implement that as many times as needed.  You can try to define the template delegate in a ref class, but then you can't make it public or even internal which defeats the purpose.  However, you can have a reference to a delegate instance in a native class.  E.g. you can accept a C++CX delegate as an argument for a native class and you can have it as a reference, but you can't define the type in the class itself.

Does anyone have any idea how I can have a variadic template native class consume and hold a WinRT/UWP delegate which matches the return type and variadic parameters of the template?

This template will be completely compiled to a windows runtime component and only needs to be used internally.

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to use a variadic template with a delegate.  However, I did discover that you can simply invoke standard member function pointers on ref classes - something I had, falsely, somewhat "assumed" one couldn't do as I don't believe you could do this in C++/CLI without marshaling (I'm still getting it through my "programming" that these are entirely different platforms despite syntactical similarity.)

If anyone needs a variadic "delegate" for C++CX you're welcome to this code (not that it's particularly complex)...  You can't export generics/templates in runtime components anyway so it's not like you're going to have out of assembly type problems.

```
template<typename MemberTyp, typename ReturnTyp, typename ...ParamTyps>
private ref class UWPDelegate
{       
public:
    typedef ReturnTyp(MemberTyp::*myFPTyp)(ParamTyps...);
private:        
    myFPTyp fp;
    MemberTyp ^instance;

internal:
    UWPDelegate(MemberTyp^ targetObject, myFPTyp targetMethod);

    ReturnTyp operator()(ParamTyps... args);

};

template<typename MemberTyp, typename ReturnTyp, typename ...ParamTyps>
inline UWPDelegate<MemberTyp, ReturnTyp, ParamTyps...>::UWPDelegate(MemberTyp ^ targetObject, myFPTyp targetMethod)
{
    fp = targetMethod;
    instance = targetObject;
}

template<typename MemberTyp, typename ReturnTyp, typename ...ParamTyps>
inline ReturnTyp UWPDelegate<MemberTyp, ReturnTyp, ParamTyps...>::operator()(ParamTyps ...args)
{
    return (instance->*fp)(args...);
}
```

You can then use this in a native class template to accept variadic delegate arguments.